# Как избежать сбрасывания состояния View после нажатия кнопки Home

Tags: java, android

Есть Активити, в ней создаются фрагменты. Во фрагментах вьюхи. Допустим мы что-то ввели в поле ввода. Нажимаем кнопку Home, приложение сворачивается, разворачиваем обратно, введенного текста уже нет.

Как избежать данной особенности?

Comment: Скорее всего приложение просто выгружается из памяти, так как этого по сути происходить не должно.

Answer (score 2):

`View`, имеющие `id`, должны сохранять и восстанавливать свое состояние автоматически (*в пределах сессии приложения*), но если этого не происходит, Вы можете реализовать сохранение состояния вручную, например:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String EDIT_TEXT_SAVE_KEY = "EDIT_TEXT_SAVE_KEY";

    private EditText mEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String savedText = savedInstanceState.getString(EDIT_TEXT_SAVE_KEY);
            mEditText.setText(savedText);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(EDIT_TEXT_SAVE_KEY, mEditText.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Дабы избежать бойлерплейт-кода, можно использовать [Icepick](https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick).

Если этот совет не помогает, то приложение выгружается из памяти, и *сброс* состояния приложения -- это нормальное явление. Если же принципиально требуется сохранять данные полей ввода, можете воспользоваться, например, `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 1):

В своих приложениях для подобного рода задач я всегда использую эти параметры в главной активности:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    ...
    android:taskAffinity=""
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Подробнее Вы можете прочитать тут: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Это плохое решение, так как есть очень много ситуаций, помимо `keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize`, при которых активити может быть пересоздана. Например, система может прибить активити, когда приложение находится в фоне, и при возврате к этой активити отобразится ее изначальное состояние.

Comment: Но как ни странно оно работает даже в приложении которое потребляет 200+ мб оперативы. Тоесть находясь в фоне длительное время. Опять же автор не имеет ввиду именно сохранение данных, он имеет ввиду сохранение View's, тоесть чтобы активность не пересоздавалась вообще уходя в фон и обратно. И этот способ реально работает.

Comment: Считайте, что Вам просто везет -- например, много свободной RAM. В общем случае это работать не будет. Установив `do not keep activities` в developer options можете проверить мои слова.

Comment: Ну тут и сам Навадский не поможет)) и тогда автору только onSaveInstanceState в помощь